# upgrade to rspec 3 - how to replace should validate_absence_oo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shoulda, rspec3

I had a test working on rspec 2 so that if partner_id is present, agency_id should not:

```
describe "tests on deals models validations for AGENCY_ID" do   
  context "if partner_id present" do 
    before { subject.stub(:partner_id) { 2 } } 
    it { should validate_absence_of(:agency_id) }
  end
```

How to do that with rspec 3?

I tried that:

```
  it "should reject model if agency_id present AND partner_id is also already present" do
    allow(subject).to receive(:partner_id) { 2 }
    expect(Customer.new).to have(1).errors_on(:agency_id) 
  end
end
```

but it does not work, it's kind of nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

[see here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax):

```
context "if partner_id present" do 
  before { allow(subject).to receive(:partner_id) { 2 } } 
  it { is_expected.to validate_absence_of(:agency_id) }
end
```

Also, in the new syntax you may still use the old one-liner syntax:

> `should` was designed back when rspec-expectations only had a
>   should-based syntax. However, it continues to be available and work
>   even if the `:should` syntax is disabled (since that merely removes
>   `Object#should` but this is `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup#should`).

So this will also work:

```
context "if partner_id present" do 
  before { allow(subject).to receive(:partner_id) { 2 } } 
  it { should validate_absence_of(:agency_id) }
end
```